# Get NMEA data type through Retrofit

Tags: java, android

I am wondering how can I get NMEA data type. It would be best if I could achieve this with Retrofit. The IP address of this data is http://213.73.2.250:5018. It looks like this: [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80oMO.jpg)

I have tried this with retrofit with this code:

```
     public void getRestDataListRetrofit(final ViewMvpTextViewLocation viewMvpTextViewLocation) throws IOException {

    Call<String> result = Api.getClient().getString();
    result.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
            viewMvpTextViewLocation.dismissProgressDialogWithSuccess(response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            viewMvpTextViewLocation.dismissProgressDialogWithError(call.request().toString() + " " + t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

where Api class is

```
public class Api {

public static ApiInterface getClient() {

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://213.73.2.250:5018/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
  }
}
```

and getString() method is

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@GET("/")
Call<String> getString();
}
```

When I click the button to receive this data I get with error: "unexpected status line: $GPGGA, (...) ". What is wrong with this code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your NMEA data lines come just as in a plain text file. So how are you threating those lines?

Comment: I have changed Retrofit return type to List<String> but it stilll gives me the same error.

Comment: But you will not get a list. I think you will just get one string containing all those lines. After that you could yourself make a list for those lines.

Comment: Ok, I updated my post but still it does not work. What should I do next? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround by parsing an error message that contains a text I wanted to have.